# How to realize expr function in FreeBSD the same way as in CentOS?

Tags: bash, centos, freebsd

I want to get a number from a file and increment it. File always contain only one number.
So in Linux (CentOS) I can do something like that:

```
Tmp="an_num.tmp"
Tmpg=$(cat $Tmp)
Tmpi=$(expr $Tmpg + 1)
```

But I can't do the same in FreeBSD. As I understand, FreeBSD's expr version is not support incrementing variable: expr $Tmpg + 1

```
$ Tmp="an_num.tmp"
$ Tmpg=$(cat $Tmp)
$ Tmpi=$(expr $Tmpg + 1)
expr: syntax error
```

But how I can realize it?

> $ uname -a FreeBSD srv 11.0-RELEASE-p1 FreeBSD 11.0-RELEASE-p1 #0
>   r306420: Thu Sep 29 01:43:23 UTC 2016
>   root@releng2.nyi.freebsd.org:/usr/obj/usr/src/sys/GENERIC  amd64

Comment: If an_num.tmp contains an integer (and *only* a single integer, and maybe a newline character), this should work in any POSIX-compliant OS and shell. Exactly what does an_num.tmp contain (you can dump it in hexadecimal with `od -x an_num.tmp`)? Also, try `set -x` before these commands so it'll print out exactly what's being executed as it runs. Add the results to your question.

Comment: Sorry, the problem was with a "read" command in the other part of my sh script - different behavior of "read" in the FreeBSD cause to zeroing "Tmp" variable

Comment: How can I close this question?

Answer (score 0):

FreeBSD uses different shell by default. Install bash (`pkg install bash`), run it with `bash` and then run your scripts there. Alternatively, use shebang line `#!/usr/local/bin/bash`.

Comment: More: https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/articles/linux-users/shells.html

Answer (score 0):

/bin/sh under FreeBSD does not support $() notation in the way you're expecting, use backticks (``) instead:

Tested on 11.1-RELEASE-p4 under /bin/sh:

```
Tmp="an_num.tmp"
Tmpg=`cat $Tmp`
Tmpi=`expr $Tmpg + 1`
```